# Where have I mixed up my math logic for this Javascript problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, logic

I was doing this challenge on HackerRank and I got it right with one small mistake. Using the test example, you have an array of 5 numbers and you must find the largest and lowest sum using 4 of the 5 numbers. You must then print the two numbers with the smaller number first and larger one second. To achieve this, I made this:

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    var smallestNumber = arr[0];
    var biggestNumber = arr[0];
    var large = 0;
    var small = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(smallestNumber < arr[i]){
            smallestNumber = arr[i];
        }
        large += arr[i];
    }

    large = large - smallestNumber;

    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        if(biggestNumber > arr[j]){
            biggestNumber = arr[j];
        }
        small += arr[j];
    }

    small = small - biggestNumber; 

    console.log(small,large);


}
```

Now technically I have the right answer, but I have them reversed. When running the code my small variable is actually the larger number and the large variable is the smaller number. All I have to do is swap the variables in the console.log and the challenge is completed, but I'm going through the code and I'm not sure where I mixed them up. As far as I'm aware, the first loop finds the smallest number in the array and then after adding all the numbers in the array, subtracks the smallest number from the total. And the second loop adds all the numbers in the array and then subtracts the largest number from the total. And yet apparently what I have is the other way around. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your comparisons are backwards. "If the smallest number is smaller than the current number in the array, set the smallest number to that." Backwards.

Comment: arr = arr.sort()

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I'm not sure I follow how that's backwards. That's what it's supposed to do. Once it goes through the array the variable should be equal to whatever the smallest number in the array is.

Comment: Your logic keeps `smallestNumber` as the *largest* number, and vice-versa. Just turn the `<` and `>` around.